# Genitive ending: why тихий - тихого when хороший - хорошего?

Tags: склонение

Why would the ending "-ого" be used in the genitive of the adjective тихий (тихого) while the ending "-его" be used in the genitive of such an adjective as хороший (хорошего) since both adjectives end in an unstressed final stem consonant being one of (ж,ш,ч,щ,г,к,х)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's consider the group of adjectives with the stress on the stem ending with **г, к, х**, and **ж, ш, ч, щ**.
The adjectives with a stem ending in letters **к, г, х, ж, ш, ч, щ** have the masculine singular ending -ий (маленький - small), the feminine singular ending in -ая (маленькая), and the plural ending -ие (маленькие).

**BUT**:In the neuter singular such adjectives end in **-oe** after **г, к, х** (маленькое), and end in **-ee** after **ж, ш, ч, щ** if the stress is on the stem (свежее молоко - fresh milk) That's where the difference starts.

The group with **г, к, х** will have the following endings.

> Долгий, долгого, долгому.
>   Мягкий, мягкого, мягкому. 
>   Тихий, тихого, тихому.

The other group with **ж, ш, ч, щ** will have the following endings.

> Хороший, хорошего, хорошему.
>   Горячий, горячего, горячему.
>   Свежий, свежего, свежему.
>   Блестящий, блестящего, блестящему.